# line separator between a relativelayout and a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

hello I have a view with a title at top and a listView with pulltorefresh functionality.

I would like to show the line separator before the first item in the listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/background_azul"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@color/usualBike"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noticesLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tituloNoticias"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/View01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#3b5998"/>

<com.mypackage.myapp.PullToRefresh
    android:id="@+id/listNews"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    android:divider="#3b5998"
    android:dividerHeight="2dip"/>           

</LinearLayout>
```

But the line is not shown. How should I do this?

Comment: the code seems okay ... isyour background and separator's color same?

Comment: ohhh! it's not the same than the background, but it's the same than the TextView layout! I can't see it because is the same!! Thanks, yours is the solution, if you post it as answer I'll mark as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems okay ... to place a separator it is enough to use the View you used. To use a separator the common practice is

```
< ViewGroup

....... />

< View

......../>

< ViewGroup

......../>
```

The only reason that you are not saying may be background color you used in the View. IF you use same color as its parent then it will not be visible